# What happened with Ruby 1.9.2?

Tags: ruby, ruby-1.9

I have seen that there is no updates for Ruby 1.9.2. (Only for Ruby 1.9.3 & 2.0). My question is: what happened with 1.9.2?

I'm confused if 1.9.3 and 1.9.2 are different branches, or 1.9.3 is the sequel, and if my 1.9.2 app will works with 1.9.3 without problems.

Comment: It was superseded by Ruby 1.9.3?

Comment: I was confused if that was another branch

Comment: I haven't downvoted your question, but I suspect you're being downvoted because you haven't explained very well what you're asking. Are you talking about the updates to deal with CVE-2013-4073, and are you worried about the compatibility of MRI Ruby 1.9.3 with code written for Ruby 1.9.2?

Comment: What's preventing you from upgrading from ruby 1.9.2 to ruby 1.9.3?

Comment: I'm wondering about the value/utility of the question that couldn't have been figured out by trying it.

Comment: @theTinMan depends on how much yak shaving is involved with installing Ruby 1.9.3.

Comment: How are we supposed to know if your app will work? You should try it for yourself! You may be pleasantly surprised.

Comment: Yak shaving? Installing 1.9.3 is an easy process, even from source, if 1.9.2 is already installed. On Macs and Linux, a simple step of storing the names of the previously installed gems (`gem list | cut -d' ' -f1 > ~/gem_list`) will turn reloading the gems into a an easy step (`xargs gem install < ~/gem_list`). On Windows... it's easier to switch to Linux.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're talking about updates to deal with CVE-2013-4073, then Ruby-lang.org [says](http://www.ruby-lang.org/en/news/2013/06/27/hostname-check-bypassing-vulnerability-in-openssl-client-cve-2013-4073/):

> All users are recommended to upgrade to Ruby 2.0.0-p247, 1.9.3-p448 or
>   1.8.7-p374.

Presumably, anyone using MRI Ruby 1.9.2 is able to use MRI Ruby 1.9.3.